# Name cannot be found in the name scope of 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.BusyIndicator'

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I am trying to achieve Text scrolling in BusyIndicator, using the bellow XAML. I am getting exception related to accessing TargetName. Can someone assist?

Code behind

```
// Locate Storyboard resource
Storyboard s = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("animation");
s.Begin(bsi_Indicator);
```

XAML code:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" x:Name="bsi_Indicator">
        <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>  
            <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="4">
                        <Canvas Name="canvas1" Height="32" ClipToBounds="True"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Name="ScrollText" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.WaitText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" >
                            <TextBlock.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollText" From="0" To="-50" Duration="0:0:10"  />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </TextBlock.Resources>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Canvas>
                        <ProgressBar Value="100" Height="20"/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>

        <xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
        <ContentControl />
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

Error:

```
Additional information: 'ScrollText' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.BusyIndicator'.
```

Comment: Try to replace `Name="ScrollText"` with `x:Name="ScrollText"` and see if that works.

Comment: this was my original impelementation.. didnt worked either

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Storyboard` is defined in the `Window` resources for example if that's your main control.

It can't find `ScrollText` because it's not in the scope of the **Parent control** which again might be `Window` **it can be anything**. It is also loaded in a `BusyContentTemplate` which might be different on how `DataTemplate` works with `Xceed` it might be lazy loaded so a possibility is that it is not there.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dp = bsi_Indicator.BusyContentTemplate.LoadContent() as StackPanel;
    var canvas = dp.Children[0] as Canvas;
    var textBlock = canvas.Children[0] as TextBlock;
    var sb = textBlock.Resources["animation"] as Storyboard;
    sb.Begin(textBlock); // you can just call sb.Begin() too
}
```